# Concatenate variable to a String in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#myImg" + i).wrap("<a id='lightboxxx'" + i "'></a>");
```

Inside a loop I am trying to specify a tag by `lightboxxx` id. `i` is the index of the loop.

I have a syntax problem with the concatenation of `i` to lightobxxx id. Every time I get:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

I already tried 12 different ways of notation. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `+` to concatenate after the second `i`. Also the quotes will be mismatched in the `id` attribute. Try this:

```
$('#myImg' + i).wrap('<a id="lightboxxx' + i + '"></a>');
```

Comment: That debatable, but it does help to use `"` to delimit your HTML attributes, which is preferred syntax.